# Getting ORA-00904: "DECL_OBJ#": invalid identifier while loading data using informatica tool in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can someone please help to resolve the below error which is occuring while trying to insert records from Oracle Database A to Database B using Informatica tool:

ORA-00904: "DECL_OBJ#": invalid identifier

Comment: So that's a table or column which doesn't exist in your target database or your source database.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with SQL Developer.

Tools --> Preferences --> Database --> PL/SQL Compiler

PLScope Identifiers : **None**

Set to **None**